# Represent a system of nonlinear equations in compact form

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

If a system of linear equations can be represented by the compact form, $$Ax=b$$ how will a system of nonlinear equations (system of quadratic equations and system of exponential equations) be represented in compact form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way too general. Perhaps something can be said about quadratic equations: you can write them as $x^*Ax + b^*x +c=0$, where $x$ is the vector of unknowns, b is a vector and c is a scalar. But a system of such things... That would require 3-dimensional matrices, and it would not be nice. If you think about the degree of freedom: you need two dimensions for all variations of the form $x_ix_j$, and a third one for the different equations.

As for exponential equations, I am not even sure what you mean, and what the degree of freedom would be. I do not think there is a compact form.